# How to load entries data in the General Configuration file?

Tags: url, config

I'm trying to set dynamic paths for values such as `activateAccountSuccessPath`.

This kind of code below from my `routes.php` file works very well:

```
use craft\elements\Entry;

$myAccount = Entry::find()->section('myAccount');

return [
    $myAccount->type('user')->one()->uri . '/<id>-<slug>' => ['template' => '_myAccount/user']
];
```

But it seems that `craft\elements\Entry` can't be used at the top of `general.php` (which make sense...).

Any idea of a simple workaround to load Entry data at this time? Like this, I could set dynamic paths depending of the context and language.

I know I could already set paths like this:

```
'activateAccountSuccessPath' => array(
     'fr' => 'mon-compte',
     'nl' => 'mijn-account'
),
```

But this is not enough, I would like the path match dynamically another existing URI in a Structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you take a look at the Docs you'll see

> See [craft\helpers\ConfigHelper::localizedValue()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-helpers-confighelper.html#method-localizedvalue) for a list of supported value types.

And that contains

> - $value (mixed) – The config setting value. This can be specified in one of the following forms:
> - A scalar value or null: represents the desired value directly, and will be returned verbatim.
> - An associative array: represents the desired values across all sites, indexed by site handles. If a matching site handle isn’t listed, the first value will be returned.
> - A PHP callable: either an anonymous function or an array representing a class method ([$class or $object, $method]). The callable will be passed the site handle if known, and should return the desired config value.
> - $siteHandle (string, null) – The site handle the value should be defined for. Defaults to the current site.
>     Returns

The interesting thing is `a function`

```PHP
'activateAccountSuccessPath' => function(){
    return Entry::find()->section('myAccount')..... // do your thing
}
```